# Query a JSONObject in java

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I was wondering if somewhere out there exists a java library able to query a JSONObject. In more depth I'm looking for something like:

```java
String json = "{ data: { data2 : { value : 'hello'}}}";

...
// Somehow we managed to convert json to jsonObject
...

String result = jsonObject.getAsString("data.data2.value");

System.out.println(result);
```

I expect to get "hello" as output.

So far, the fastest way I have found is using Gson:

```java
jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("data").getAsJsonObject().get("data2").getAsJsonObject("value").getAsString();
```

It's not actually easy to write and read. Is there something faster?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I've just unexpectedly found very interesting project: [JSON Path](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath)

> JsonPath is to JSON what XPATH is to XML, a simple way to extract parts of a given document.

With this library you can do what you are requesting even easier, then my previous suggestion:

```
String hello = JsonPath.read(json, "$.data.data2.value");

System.out.println(hello); //prints hello
```

Hope this might be helpful either.

Comment: looks exactly what we need, explanation with sample is very useful any one can good to go with

Comment: problem is that afaik does not support retrieving parents

Answer (score 31):

While not exactly the same, Jackson has Tree Model representation similar to Gson:

```
JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(jsonInput);
return root.get("data").get("data2").get("value").asText();
```

so you need to traverse it step by step.

**EDIT** (August 2015)

There actually is now (since Jackson 2.3) support for [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) expressions with Jackson. So you could alternatively use:

```
return root.at("/data/data2/value").asText();
```

Comment: You can change `get` to `path` to avoid nulls.

Comment: Is there anything similar in Gson?

Answer (score 17):

First of all, I would recommend consider JSON object binding.

But in case if you get arbitrary JSON objects and you would like process them in the way you described, I would suggest combine [Jackson JSON processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) along with Apache's [Commons Beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

The idea is the following: Jackson by default process all JSON's as `java.util.Map` instances, meanwhile Commons Beanutils simplifies property access for objects, including arrays and Map supports.

So you may use it something like this:

```
//actually it is a Map instance with maps-fields within
Object jsonObj = objectMapper.readValue(json, Object.class);

Object hello = PropertyUtils.getProperty(jsonObj, "data.data2.value")

System.out.println(hello); //prints hello
```

Comment: Yes, I already considered object binding (and actually is the way I usually follow). But a project I'm working on has a really big JSON to manage and its structure changes a lot by time. It's really time consuming following every change by binding objects. Thanks a lot for your suggestion :)

Comment: Does this work for those keys that have "." in them? Like if one key was "link.required" and its node had something like "number", would "link.required.number" work?

Answer (score 6):

You can use org.json

```
    String json = "{ data: { data2 : { value : 'hello'}}}";
    org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject(json);
    System.out.println(obj.query("/data/data2/value"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that works also with the current Java version (21) and also offers [validation functionality](https://dev.to/jjbrt/querying-and-validating-a-json-document-in-java-323i) is the [Burningwave JSON](https://burningwave.github.io/json/) library:

```java
String json = "{ data: { data2 : { value : 'hello'}}}";
Facade facade = Facade.create(new ObjectMapper());
ObjectHandler jsonObjectHandler = facade.newObjectHandler(json , Map.class);
String value = jsonObjectHandler.newValueFinder().findFirstForPathEndsWith("value");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think no way.

Consider a java class

```
class Student {
    Subject subject = new Subject();
}

class Subject {
    String name;
}
```

Here if we want to access subject name then

```
Student stud = new Student();
stud.subject.name;
```

We cant access name directly, if so then we will not get correct subject name. Like here:

```
jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("data")
          .getAsJsonObject()
          .get("data2")
          .getAsJsonObject("value")
          .getAsString();
```

If you want to use same like java object then use

```
ClassName classObject = new Gson().fromJson(JsonString, ClassName.class);
```

ClassName must have all fields to match jsonstring. If you have a jsonobject inside a jsonobject then you have to create separate class like I'm doing in Student and Subject class.

Comment: I know what object binding is, and usually it's the way I follow when managing json :) But I was looking for a faster way (sometime it's really too time consuming making beans for something really simple as in the example I suggested).

Answer (score 1):

Using Java JSON API 1.1.x (javax.json) one can make use of new `JavaPointer` interface. Instance implementing this interface can be considered to some extend as kind of XPath expression analog (see [RFC-6901](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) for details). So in your case you could write this:

```java
import javax.json.*;
//...
var jp = Json.createPointer("/data/data2/value");
System.out.println(jp.getValue(jsonObject));
```

In 1.1.4 version of JSON there's also nice addition to `JsonStructure` interface (which is implemented by `JsonObject` and `JsonArray`), namely `getValue(String jsonPointer)`. So it all comes down to this simple one-liner:

```java
System.out.println(jsonObject.getValue("/data/data2/value"));
```