# How to query a json object in java?

Tags: java, json

I have a `test.json` file with data:

```
{
  "name":"tet",
  "id":"1",
  "age" : "34"
}
```

Now when I query `select * from test;` should show me the result as

```
name id age
-----------
tet  1   34
```

Is it possible to directly query a JSON Object as we do for XML?

Comment: What JSON library are you using? Is it JSR-353 one or something else?

Comment: I think you can implement your own Query builder based on the query you can fetch the records from the JSON object, you can refer Hibernate Query implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The popular Jackson XML library supports [JsonPointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) since version 2.3. This is a query language similar to XPath

Input

```
[{
  "name":"tet",
  "id":"1",
  "age" : "34"
},{
  "name":"tet",
  "id":"1",
  "age" : "34"
},{
  "name":"tet",
  "id":"1",
  "age" : "34"
},{
  "name":"tet",
  "id":"1",
  "age" : "34"
}]
```

Example

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(new File("foo.json"));
System.out.println(root.at("/0/name").asText());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can either try looking for a library which allows you to search throught JSON data or to convert your json to JSONObjects and query your data in a Object Oriented way.

Perhaps this thread will help:

[Query a JSONObject in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429775/query-a-jsonobject-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to query directly from the Json, if you want you have to create a new class that will do your requirement, OR you can use the ObjectMapper (download and add to your class path) from jackson-all-1.9.0.jar, and create a new transfer Object TestTO.java expose the setters and getters you will get your data like below..

1.create TestTO.java

```
public class TestTO{

private String name;
private int id;
private int age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

}

2.read your data from the object.

```
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Test test = mapper.readValue(yourJson.json, TestTO.class);
            String name = test.getName();
            int id = test.getId();
            int age = test.getAge();
```

if your json contains the multiple test objects, use an test array like below, it will give you the array of tests, you can iterate over and get the data, like below.

```
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            TestTO[] test = mapper.readValue(yourJson.json, TestTO.class[]);
            for(Test tst:test){
            String name = test.getName();
            int id = test.getId();
            int age = test.getAge();
           }
```