# Dynamic way to access JSON nested values in Java

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have this JSON object:

```
{
    "maindrawer":
    {
        "enabled": true,
        "actions":
        [
            {
                "type": "Section",
                "title": "Section 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "type": "Primary",
                "title": "Title 1",
                "badge":
                {
                    "enabled": false,
                    "value": 0,
                    "textColor": "#000000",
                    "badgeColor": "#ff0990"
                },
                "subActions":
                [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "type": "Primary",
                        "title": "Sub Title 1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the code I'm using to access the badge -> textColor value:

```
public void loadJSONFromRaw(Context context, int id)
{
    json = null;
    try
    {
        //read and return json sting
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(id);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

        //convert json to object
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
        Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);

        //access maindrawer property
        Map<String, Object> maindrawer = (Map<String, Object>)data.get("maindrawer");

        //access actions list
        List<Object> actions = (List<Object>)maindrawer.get("actions");

        //return first item in the list
        Map<String, Object> action = (Map<String, Object>) actions.get(1);

        //return badge object
        Map<String, String> badge = (Map<String, String>) action.get("badge");

        //access badge -> textColor value
        String textColor = badge.get("textColor");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there a better/faster or more dynamic way to access JSON nested properties using java/android? I'm using Gson library for this task and don't mind to switch to any other solution to make it easier as this is too much of code to write just to access a single variable.

Ideally, I'm looking for something like:

```
String textColor = data.get("maindrawer").get("actions").get(1).get("badge").get("textColor");
```

Also I'm not very interested in using POJO for now.

Lastly, I'm still new to Java so I'm probably missing something here or maybe there are some limitations? anyways thanks for you help!!

Comment: The thing you are expected are the same as your code above just missing some casting.

Comment: I'm curious as to what the state of the art is for this sort of thing in java. The code you posted is WAY too long.

Comment: @RobertMoskal - That's what I'm trying to achieve. Within PHP I can simply pass in something like: $data['maindrawer']['actions']['0']['badge']['textColor']; which is very straightforward. Not sure if that's achievable with java

Comment: Possibly related: [Query a JSONObject in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429775/query-a-jsonobject-in-java)

Comment: Are you married to Gson? I think Jackson would be better for this.

Comment: Or you can try [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

Comment: @shmosel - That's what I found out from Pshemo's comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found what I need using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library. It looks like it does similar to what I need. Here's a sample code I found:

```
String textColor = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.maindrawer.actions[1].badge.textColor");
```

Very clean and straightforward. Hopes this will save someone else's time as well.

Comment: Next time I need to do this sort of thing in java I will remember!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are accessing json file locally, it means you know its structure.
So instead of using -
`Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);`

You can use something like this-

`Map<String, MainDrawer> data = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);`

where `MainDrawer` is a class with member variables - `enabled`, `actions` and array of another type.

That would make easier to fetch your values like using -
`mainDrawer.isEnabled()`

Comment: The OP doesn't want to use POJO

Comment: I know it's doable with POJO but that's not my aim.

Comment: Yeah, no one should have to create a class in order to extract a single value! Come on it's 2017!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions without importing a new library.

Write a simple path parser:

```
String textColor = (String)parse(data, "maindrawer", "actions", 1, "badge", "textColor");

//...

static Object parse(Object root, Object... params) {
    Object current = root;
    for (Object p : params) {
        if (p instanceof Number) {
            current = ((List<?>)current).get(((Number)p).intValue());
        } else {
            current = ((Map<?,?>)current).get(p.toString());
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```

Or parse and walk through Gson's `JsonElement`:

```
JsonElement root = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
String textColor = root
        .getAsJsonObject().get("maindrawer")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("actions")
        .getAsJsonArray().get(1)
        .getAsJsonObject().get("badge")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("textColor")
        .getAsString();
```

Comment: looks promising now sure how it will handle different types like integers, booleans or arrays etc...

Comment: @SolidSnake Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: sorry typo.. I meant I'm not sure how the first method will handle the different data types like if I wanted to get the whole actions array. would I need to cast the returned value as a List<object>?

Comment: @SolidSnake You can cast it to `List<?>`, like the method does.

Comment: Thanks I'll test it

Comment: The second option is sort of ok :). It does kind of make me wistful for xml and xpath!

Comment: @RobertMoskal I'm not that familiar with Gson, but I know that Jackson has much cleaner solutions out of the box. One is very similar to OP's proposed syntax; the other is similar to JsonPath. But my assumption was that OP is settled on Gson.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with BSON using a single line query.  You have to cast the object to the type as you go down into Nested JSON objects.

```
 //import java.util.ArrayList;
 //import org.bson.Document;


 Document root = Document.parse("{ \"maindrawer\" : { \"enabled\" : true, \"actions\" : [{ \"type\" : \"Section\", \"title\" : \"Section 1\" }, { \"id\" : 1, \"type\" : \"Primary\", \"title\" : \"Title 1\", \"badge\" : { \"enabled\" : false, \"value\" : 0, \"textColor\" : \"#000000\", \"badgeColor\" : \"#ff0990\" }, \"subActions\" : [{ \"id\" : 1, \"type\" : \"Primary\", \"title\" : \"Sub Title 1\" }] }] } }");


 System.out.println(((String)((Document)((Document)((ArrayList)((Document)root.get("maindrawer")).get("actions")).get(1)).get("badge")).get("textColor")));
```