# Read a particular object on the basis of value in java

Tags: java, json

I have some json data

```
{
 "attributesMappings": [
   {
     "domainType": "WI",
     "attribute": [
       {
        "staticAttributes": [
          {
            "attributeName": "test",
            "attributeValue": "test",
            "required": true
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     "domainType": "PI",
     "attribute": null
   }
 ]
}
```

I can read the object using

```
JSONArray vendorData = mainObj.getJSONArray("attributesMappings");
```

Suppose I want to get only the object where where domain type ="WI", I know it can be done using

```
JSONObject obj = vendorData.getJSONObject(0);
```

And then I can perform the manipulations, suppose I dont know at what index "WI" will be stored, is there a way of getting the data. I know we can iterate over the array items and match for domainType.

Can we do it in a way whereby using "WI" in the getJSONObject or something of that sort I can get the complete object.

```
JSONObject domainType = attributeMappings.getJSONObject("WI");
```

Comment: *I know we can iterate over the array items and match for domainType.* So what's the problem?

Comment: Finding a more efficient way of doing it. Suppose the data is deeply nested, then it's a big problem.

Comment: There's nothing you can do about that. You can build a map to avoid iterating for multiple lookups, but it won't be worthwhile if it's just one value you're after.

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller How does a JavaScript question help for Java?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no **more efficient** way of searching a JSON object tree than iterating it.  But the cost of searching will actually be small compared with the cost of parsing the object tree.

You could potentially do better than the "parse to JSONObject" using a stream-based parser, and coding your parse event handlers to look for the information you are trying to extract.  If the information you are looking for is near the beginning of the JSON serialization, you could save time by abandoning the parse as soon as you get a search "hit".

If you only doing one search of the JSON, that is the end of the story.

If you are going to search the same JSON repeatedly, then the way to get better performance is:

1. Parse the JSON tree, or map it to a POJO tree
2. Construct a separate index data structure for the in-memory tree.
3. Use the index to speed up searches.

So, in your example you might build an index for all attribute mappings based on the `domainType` field.

Alternatively, extract *just* the information you want into a data structure that is designed for your needs.

---

There are libraries around that do the equivalent of XQuery and XPath for JSON.  This approach is definitely *more convenient* than writing a bunch of iteration code; e.g. (from @cricket_007's comment):

> The JSONPath query *[for your example]* would be `$.attributesMappings[?(@.domainType == "WI")]`

For more information: [Query a JSONObject in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429775/query-a-jsonobject-in-java)

However, I would be hesitant to use "JSON query" libraries if you are looking for a *more efficient* solution.

Comment: To add comment: The JSONPath query would be `$.attributesMappings[?(@.domainType == "WI")]`