# How get nested value by key divided by dot using Java?

Tags: java, json, nested

So, suppose I have the next JSON object:

```
{
   "key1": {
      "key11": "value11",
      "key12": {
         "key121": "value121",
         "key122": "value122",
         "key123": "value123"
      }
   },
   "key2": "value2",
   "key3": "value3"
}
```

And I have the nested key divided by dot: `key1.key12.key122`. Goal will be to get  `value122` by this key.

I wrote the next solution:

```
public List<String> getEntityValuesByKeys(JSONObject entity, List<String> keys) {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONObject entityCopy = new JSONObject(entity.toString());

    for (String key : keys) {
        String[] nestedKeys = key.split("\\.");
        for (String nestedKey : nestedKeys) {
            if (entityCopy.get(nestedKey) instanceof JSONObject) {
                entityCopy = new JSONObject(entityCopy.get(nestedKey).toString());
            } else {
                values.add(entityCopy.get(nestedKey).toString());
            }
        }
        entityCopy = new JSONObject(entity.toString());
    }

    return values.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Is it some java libraries that make something like this?

I don't know beforehand how deep will be JSON and how nested will be a key. It can has only one nested step like: `key1`, and like in exapmle higher in one method calling.

All input parameters and returned value must be the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related: [Query a JSONObject in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15429775)

Comment: What is the problem with the solution you have written?

Comment: @Pshemo, thanks, it work perfect!