# Creating map based on json given

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

**JSON**

```
{
 "type": {
   "type1": {
     "sub1": [
        "sub1A": {
        }
     ]
   }
 }
"type2": {
   "type1": {
     "sub1": [
        "sub1A": {
        }
     ]
   }
 }
```

}

I have Json like this , I am not getting how to create map for this, like

```
Map<String, Object> requestMap = new HashMap<>();
requestMap.get("type");
```

Inside type again create map containing sub data.

Comment: Use a JSON library to parse the JSON, and it will give you a Map of Map (x5) in return. --- Well, except that it would fail, since that is not valid JSON. It would be valid if you replaced the `[]` with `{}`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question completely. But, from your statement, if you are trying to fetch json data into your class and that JSON data has recursive mapping, i.e., one object contains itself under its body. Then, I don't think you need HashMap to map this json into your class. You can use single Entity with a field of type of itself like employee-manager relationship. e.g.,

```
class Type {
  private Type type;
  private String otherField;
  // constructors, setters, getters
}
```

Now, you can read values from type using the recursive functions.

Answer (score -1):

According to what you have shared you can use:

```
Map <String, Map<String, Map<String, Set<Map<String, String>>>>>
```

Or to get more details concerning working with json objects you can look at: [Query a JSONObject in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429775/query-a-jsonobject-in-java)

Comment: `Set`? It only has 1 type parameter. Yours has 2. Compile error!!! --- And the JSON shown is not valid, so it wouldn't become anything except a parse exception.

Comment: There are two things, either this is not a valid json or it just an object he wants to store and just named it as json. If we are sure we are getting a json then obviously there is an error as you mentioned and the best method then will be to use JSONObject (https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html). But if the second case is true then what I have mentioned(edited) is correct.