# How to show data by ID in TableView from JSON

Tags: php, mysql, swift, xcode, uitableview

I get the data from JSON and also can show it in UITableView, but can I show the data where id is = 1 for example? just like SQL? Thanks for help in advance. Here is my code. I have 2 TableViews, first one holds 3 users and the 2nd one should have that user Information, but when I click on one user it shows all the information from all users.

```
import UIKit

struct User: Codable {
let firstName: String
let lastName: String
let email: String
let userid: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case firstName = "first_name"
    case lastName = "last_name"
    case email = "email"
    case userid = "user_id"
}
}

class tableViewCellLabels: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var lbl_firstName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lbl_lastName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lbl_email: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lbl_userid: UILabel!

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableview1: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var tableview2: UITableView!
private var dataSource = [User]() {
    didSet {
        self.tableview1.reloadData()
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableview1.dataSource = self
    self.tableview1.delegate = self

    let url = URL(string: "https://test.netperformers.de/users")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "An error occurred")
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.dataSource = try! JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)
        }
    }).resume()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableview1.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == tableView{
        print(dataSource[indexPath.row]) // your clicked user data
    }else{
        // Second Tableview Click Event here
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath) as! tableViewCellLabels
    let user = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]

    cell.lbl_firstName.text = user.firstName
    cell.lbl_lastName.text = user.lastName
    cell.lbl_userid.text = user.userid
    return cell
}
func tableView1(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == tableView{
        print(dataSource[indexPath.row]) // your clicked user data
    }else{
        // Second Tableview Click Event here
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display data in ascending order by **user_id**?

Comment: Not in ascending order, for example I get 10 users from JSON and want to only show the 3rd one (ofcourse all data are sorted by ID in JSON)

Comment: Please Check my answer.

Comment: What does the MySQL tag does to have to do with this.. Also Java has a [JSONObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) class which supports [jsonpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429775/query-a-jsonobject-in-java) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a 2nd `UITableVIew` to show a single `User`, its not the correct purpose of this ui control, instead you can do one of followings:

- Show `UIAlertController` with the user information

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      let user = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]

      let alertController = UIAlertController(title: user.firstName + " " + user.lastName, message: user.email, preferredStyle: .alert)
      let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
      alertController.addAction(action)
      self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  ```
- Create a `UIViewController` to have a UI that matches your needs, following is a basic example

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      let user = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
      let userVC = UserViewController(user: user)
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(userVC, animated: true)
  }

  class UserViewController: UIViewController {

      private let user: User

      init(user: User) {
          self.user = user
          super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
      }

      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
      }

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          self.view.backgroundColor = .white

          let nameLabel = UILabel()
          nameLabel.text = self.user.firstName + " " + self.user.lastName
          nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          self.view.addSubview(nameLabel)

          let emailLabel = UILabel()
          emailLabel.text = self.user.email
          emailLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          self.view.addSubview(emailLabel)

          let safeAreaGuide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
          NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
              nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
              nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
              nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 16.0),

              emailLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
              emailLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
              emailLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 16.0)
          ])
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: It works and thanks for the project, you helped me a lot many thanks. :)

Comment: Hi, just one question, what if I want to only want to show one user in the first tableview? Thanks for your help :) @AamirR

Comment: Within `URLSession.shared.dataTask` you are receiving JSON that should be only one user and within table view you will see only that user, can do that? if not than you need to explain with the required logic.

Comment: I mean I get for exp. "Amed, id = 1" and "Robin, id = 2" from JSON, but I only want to show "Amed" in the 1st tableView (And the data in the 2nd one just like now)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a filter array before reloading the tableview.

```
private var dataSource = [User]() {
    didSet {
        dataSource = dataSource.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
            return item.userid == "3" // put your filter query here
        })
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Click Event

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == YourFirstTable {
        print(dataSource[indexPath.row]) // your clicked user data
    } else {
        // Second Tableview Click Event here
    }

}
```

Comment: This is nice thank, but what if I have a Table View with 3 users, and if you click on one users the app should show me only the informations from that user? This is my problem sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: @AmedLMAB Then you can do it with **UITableView** didSelectRowAt delegate method check please updated answer

Comment: it still shows the information from all users when I click on one, maybe because I have 2 swift files? this code is for the 1st Tableview and the 2nd tableView is same but I show only email

Comment: @AmedLMAB Dear, you can use only a single delegate method in a view controller for multiple Tableview or CollectionView so you can use it by giving the condition please remove second delegate method and handle it with a condition like this. **Please Check my Updated Answer**

Comment: I updated my code, ofcourse it's not working....., so hope you maybe can help me please. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a specific user you can filter the dataSource like this:

```
dataSource.first(where: { $0.userid == "1" })
```

Comment: I have 2 TableViews, first one holds 3 users and the 2nd one should have that user Information, but when I click on one user it shows all the information from all users.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of section Header. So all section headers will list the users. In cell for row for each section you can show the information for that particular user. Also you can manage the height of the row for managing the show hide functionality.

Let me know if this helps.