# How to access an array of object in a feature file for cucumber test?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I have a json file that is used to do certain operations and later used to compare value. The json looks like the following

```
{
 "entity": {
  "userId": "0000",
  "pos": [
   {
    "posId": "1111",
    "userPosItem": [
     {
      "id": "3333"
     },
     {
      "id": "4444"
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "posId": "2222",
    "userPosItem": [
     {
      "id": "5555"
     },
     {
      "id": "6666"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

I want to access `pos[0].userPosItem[0].id` but if written in a similar way in the feature file then I am getting an error.

The feature file looks like the following -

```
Then Topic published Event of type EventType and with
            |  entity.userId  | entity.pos[0].posId   |
            | {$model.userId} | {$model.pos[0].posId} |
```

The above check in the feature file of the cucumber test is generating error. It is also not possible to access the posId[0].userPosItem[0].id . How should I implement it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query a JSONObject in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429775/query-a-jsonobject-in-java)

Comment: What error did you get?